# Can I use a method that returns an boolean as the condition of an if statement in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

```
class my_class
    def is_same(self, arg1, arg2):
        return arg1 == arg2

    def a_function(self):
        if is_same('a', 'b'):
            print "They're the same"
```

Eclipse tells me is_same is an undefined variable. I think you can do this in Java.

Comment: Have you tried *actually running* this?

Comment: `print 'They're the same'` is a syntax error. Escape the single quote or double-quote the string.

Comment: You never even show `is_mode` in the code.

Comment: (Original code had syntax errors - missing colons at end of def and if statement lines and bad choice of string delimiter quotes - I edited to fix these.)

Comment: Thank you for fixing those errors. That is not what is causing the problem. I'm just learning Python and I'm relying heavily on the error checker in Eclipse. I can't show my actual code because it's proprietary so I tried to create this example that illustrates what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to say `self.is_same()` because these functions were inside a class. Coming from Java where you don't need to say `this.method()`, I was confused.

Answer (score 1):

`is_mode` is not anywhere in the posted code, however, there is another problem, a syntax error.

Instead of the original

```
print 'They're the same'
```

use:

```
print "They're the same"
```

You can use " " or ' ' to enclose strings, here you are using 3 of them in the same string.  There's no need to escape the ' if you use "" to surround your string.

UPDATE: There's nothing wrong with having

```
return arg1 == arg2
```

in your function, it will return a Boolean value as you expected.

Comment: Probably because it is unrelated to the error he posted.

Comment: @ThiefMaster oh ok, well it seems petty since it ***is*** an error and I don't even see `is_mode` anywhere in the code. Plus, nothing is worth less than a downvote without a comment. I know I (like everyone else) make mistakes, but it's hard for me to learn anything from this if I don't know why ..

Comment: Yeah.. unless an answer is obviously bad/wrong downvoting should go with a comment.

Comment: Sorry, my actual code is is_mode but to simplify my question, I changed the example code to is_same. The important thing is that is_mode returns a boolean and it is in the same scope as the other function.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely pydev (which I guess you are using) is being a dick again. It sometimes does not re-read everything immediately and then either keeps showing warnings where the source is already done or show warnings because it doesn't know (yet) that someone is defined. Saving the file often helps. At least if it's not busy "rebuilding" the project.

Besides the quoting error your code is perfectly fine and works as intended.

```
>>> def is_same(arg1, arg2):
...     return arg1 == arg2
...
>>> def a_function():
...     if is_same('a', 'b'):
...         print "They're the same"
...
>>> a_function()
>>>
```

However, if you really needed a function `is_same`, you would not write it like this but rather import it:

```
from operator import eq as is_same
```

Comment: I was just using is_same as an example. My is_mode function in my code does something different but returns a boolean.